# Multithreading, parallel bubble sort

Tags: java, multithreading, bubble-sort

In my java app I need to merge two ordered by bubble sort arrays, I have already created three threads, two threads to order first and last parts and I thought to Third thread to merge order arrays.

Can someone suggest me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Let the `main` define the array and create 3 threads: "bubble1", "bubble2" and "merger":

```
int[] array= ... ;
BubbleThread bubble1=new BubbleThread(array, 0, array.length/2);
BubbleThread bubble2=new BubbleThread(array, array.length/2, array.length);
Merger merger=new Merger(bubble1, bubble2);
bubble1.start();
bubble2.start();
merger.start();
```

The thread "bubble1" applies bubble sort from the beginning of the array to length/2 - 1. "merger" waits for the finish of the two threads; then merges the two sorted parts:

```
public void run() {
      bubble1.join();
      bubble2.join();
      // merge the sorted upper and lower halves of the array
}
```

Comment: But i have to merge numbers after every single iteration of external cycle of bubble sort. Thanks

Comment: That was not clear in your question. Try to include such important details in your future questions. Anyway, This synchronization between the merger and the two bubble sorters is not easy. You need to add a synchronized method in "BubbleThread" called "getNextNumber()" for example, and make it `wait()` for the next ready number. The `run()` of the BubbleThread must `signal()` at the end of every external loop iteration.